# I can't install consistent versions of vnstat

Tags: software-installation

I operate several leased VPS servers in Europe, Middle East and US.  Recently, I have  installed vnstat to monitor my network connections volume and speed.  The most recent version of vnstat is 2.6, which I like, but a few of my servers download and installed 1.15, 1.16 or 1.17.  Attempts to upgrade vnstat on these units always gives me 'newest version installed.' which is not true.  I operate Ubuntu 20.04 server on all.  I have tried to switch mirrors in sources.list to another country to no avail.  I have not tried to install from source because the extraneous downloads take valuable disk real estate.  vnstat2.6 has features I like that are not in 1.x.  Please help!

Comment: Run `apt-cache policy vnstat` on each server, you can check the latest version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) as focal [has 2.6 in the repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=vnstat).

Answer (score 0):

Your `universe` repository is disabled. As, vnStat [version 2.6 is available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/vnstat) in the universe repositories of Ubuntu 20.04. Follow these steps to install the latest version of vnStat:

1. Add the universe repository:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository universe
   ```
2. Update the repository list:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Install vnStat:

   ```
   sudo apt install --reinstall vnstat=2.6-1
   ```

You can also manually install the `.deb` files and compile the package yourself.

1. Get the `.deb` files:

   ```
   wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vnstat/vnstat_2.6-1_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Install the files:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i vnstat_2.6-1_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Update and satisfy the dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt -f install
   ```

Alternatively, you can use a custom PPA to install vnStat version **2.8**:

1. Add the PPA:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/vnstat
   ```
2. Update the repository list:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Install vnStat:

   ```
   sudo apt install --reinstall vnstat
   ```

If you're still not getting the latest version, try changing the mirror to "Main Server".